# Error converting my raw sql into eloquent code

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Hello fellow developers,
I'm trying to convert my query into eloquent code,but as I was using "CASE" commands among other commands I decided to insert the select section into a DB::raw but now I experience some syntax error or access violation:1055, here is my sql:

```
SELECT pa.id_budget_total,pa.name,CASE WHEN co.budget IS null THEN pa.amount ELSE pa.amount - SUM(co.budget) END AS left 
    FROM budget_total pa LEFT JOIN convening co ON pa.id_budget_total = co.budget_total 
    where pa.status = 1 GROUP BY pa.name
```

I kind of converted it to eloquent but when I add co.budget it tells me the error code followed by that co.budget is not group by, and yes it displays no error if I add it within the groupBy but that'd change the whole result. Here it's the eloquent code:

```
budget_total::select(DB::raw("pa.id_budget_total,pa.name, CASE WHEN co.budget IS null THEN pa.amount ELSE pa.amount - SUM(co.budget) END AS restante"))
->from("budget_total as pa")->leftJoin("convocatoria as co","pa.id_budget_total","=","co.id_budget_total")->where("pa.status", 1)
->groupBy("pa.id_budget_total","pa.name","pa.amount")->get();
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your `CASE` expression.

Comment: I'm getting all the related convening-budgets and substracting them from the total budgets but in case that there's no convening budgets related to a total budget I just print the total budget(in order to don't get a NULL value)

Comment: yeah, I'm trying already that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to always use the `ELSE` condition, but then `COALESCE` a `NULL` sum to zero.

```
budget_total::select(DB::raw("pa.id_budget_total, pa.name,
    pa.amount - COALESCE(SUM(co.budget), 0) AS restante"))
    ->from("budget_total as pa")
    ->leftJoin("convocatoria as co", "pa.id_budget_total", "=", "co.id_budget_total")
    ->where("pa.status", 1)
    ->groupBy("pa.id_budget_total", "pa.name", "pa.amount")
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tim it works perfectly! I really appreciate it!

Comment: well I just had to delete the "END" word before AS restante to get it working